# Correct interpretation of a rather convoluted sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

A question on probability has this rather convoluted sentence:

**"Within the first week (7 days), what is the probability that there were no days in which Tom went out but did not order food from a restaurant?"**

I interpreted it as meaning

[On days when] **Tom went out within the first week (7 days), there were no days in which** [he] **did not order food from a restaurant**

Is my interpretation correct, and if not, what other reasonable interpretation(s) can be put on the quoted sentence ?

Comment: For context: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4398808/conditional-probability-and-independence-using-bayes-rule-and-binomial-expansio

Comment: Within the first week (7 days), what is the probability that there were no days on which Tom did both A and B? >  A Tom went out // B Tom did not order food from a restaurant.

Comment: I provided an answer, but the reference link is to math.stackexchange.com, which handles this case in general. Also, remove all the negative phrasing where you can, such as "does not order food" becomes something like "starves". While not literally true (Tom won't literally starve), you can treat this as a substitution, and substitute "does not order food" back in at the end. It helps clarify this obviously twisted sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> Within the first week (7 days), what is the probability that there were no days in which Tom went out but did not order food from a restaurant?

The conjunction *but* is confusing you, because it actually acts like an *and* here. You are looking for the joint probability that Tom (goes out) and (doesn't eat out, which we can call *starves* to remove the negative). See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64123/what-is-the-logical-operator-for-but/64139 for an explanation.

There are four cases. Let's label them like this.

> 1. Tom stays in AND eats out: miss, Tom stayed in.
> 2. Tom stays in AND starves: miss, Tom stayed in.
> 3. Tom goes out AND eats out: miss, Tom eats out.
> 4. Tom goes out AND starves: hit.

The only *hit* is case four:

> Tom goes out BUT starves

is interpreted as

> Tom goes out AND starves.

If that event is labeled *z*, then your answer on the other board, z^7, is correct. I didn't read through enough to see if *z* here is *p*, but that part is definitely on the math side.

Comment: "doesn't eat out, which we can call starves to remove the negative" I believe the correct term is "buy no meal". The distribution of probabilities follows the buy-no-meal distribution. The question is asking for the probability of the buy-no-meal distribution taking on the value of 0.